# Apache reverse proxy security configuration

Tags: linux, http, server, .htaccess, ssl

Could someone share some light and check if this is okay for apache httpd security/good standards? I'm using apache httpd to call my Node.js app that is running with Express and also configuring SSL.

apache2.conf:

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

Protocols h2 http/1.1

KeepAlive Off

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
  StartServers 4
  MinSpareServers 20
  MaxSpareServers 40
  MaxClients 200
  MaxRequestsPerChild 4500
</IfModule>

ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off

FileETag None
TraceEnable off
```

site-name.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName www.site-name.com  
  ProxyRequests Off

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  Redirect permanent / https://site-name.com

</VirtualHost>
```

site-name-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule       mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost  _default_:443>
      ServerName site-name.com

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

      SSLEngine on
      ProxyRequests Off

      SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site-name.com/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site-name.com/privkey.pem
      Include   /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

      ProxyPass /api http://site-name.com:3000/api
      ProxyPassReverse /api http://site-name.com:3000/api

      ProxyPass / http://site-name.com:4226/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://site-name.com:4226/

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```